# Avoid long first start of gazebo

Tags: gazebo-6

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody,

I want to do some automatic test with Gazebo on a cloud machine.

Probem is : first start of Gazebo is too long and make test fail

Is there a way to avoid this behavior ? (Is there a way of avoiding contact with model repository ?)

And also is there a way to know if Gazebo has already been launched ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14107/avoid-long-first-start-of-gazebo/) by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 284 on 2016-08-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can manually install the model repository. Clone the repo into `.gazebo/models`.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) on 2016-08-16**:
It works great. Thank you.